# ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get() returning NULL when testing

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test, controller, method

**Update:**

I have changed it as proposed by @mkorman 's post to:

*Controller Class*

```
[...]
public String myId {get; set;}
[...]
public PageReference controllerMethod(){
    [...]
    System.Debug(myId);
    [...]
return NULL;
}
```

*Visualforce Page*

```
[...]
<apex:commandLink value="Button_Label" action="{!controllerMethod}" rendered="{!Object__c.BooleanField}"> 
    <apex:param name="param" value="{!Object__c.Id}" assignTo="{!myId}"/>
</apex:commandLink>
[...]
```

*Test Class*

```
[...]
VFController controller = New VFController();
[...]
controller.myId = myTestId;
controller.controllerMethod();
[...]
```

But still getting NULL in System.Debug(myId);

**Original:**

In a method (let's call it controllerMethod) of a visualforce controller class (let's call it VFController) there's this line:

```
String myId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('param');
```

that returns NULL when testing it.

That 'param' comes from the visualforce page (let's call it MyVFPage) that is controlled by that controller class:

```
<apex:commandLink value="Button_Label" action="{!controllerMethod}" rendered="{!Object__c.BooleanField}"> 
    <apex:param name="param" value="{!Object__c.Id}"/>
</apex:commandLink>
```

I have tried using

```
    PageReference VFPage = Page.MyVFPage;
    Test.setCurrentPageReference(VFPage);
    VFPage.getParameters().put('param', myTestId);
    VFControllercontroller = New VFController();
```

But still returning NULL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Test.setCurrentPageReference` is completely useless. Don't bother.

Answer (score 6):

You should use [`ApexPages.currentPage()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_System_ApexPages_currentPage.htm) method for this approach:

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('param', Id);
```

Comment: I have changed it to
 PageReference VFPage = Page.MyVFPage;
 Test.setCurrentPage(VFPage);
 ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('param', Id);
 VFControllercontroller controller = New VFController();
and still not working.

Comment: @Iliablun Try to rename your variable from `Id` to something else, for example to `myId`. I think that `Id` is reserved name.

Comment: One shouldn't need to use `ApexPages.currentPage()...` to set parameters, `anyPgRef.getParameters().put(someparamName,someparamValue)` works fine (as long as `test.setCurrentPageReference(anyPgRef)` was called beforehand.

Comment: @mast0r, the names of variables, methods, etc. are just examlpes. By the way, I have changed the code as proposed by mkorman, check the first message. Thanks to you all.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to pass an argument to a method in the same controller, you don't need to parse the query string. You can just assign the value to a public property via the "apex:param" and read it in your method.

Take a look at this:

http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/03/03/passing-parameters-with-a-commandlink/

In your case, in VFController you could:

- declare a public property called "param"
- in controllerMethod refernce param directly

Comment: I have edited the opening message after trying this. I still couldn't fix it. Thanks.